# Android App Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, boonex-dolphin

Okay,

So I'm working on an Android app but get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in
>   com.networkstudios.app.LoginActivity.
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.networkstudios.app.LoginActivity$1
>   at com.networkstudios.app.LoginActivity.(LoginActivity.java:37)
>   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2007)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is the code for LoginActivity.java found in com.networkstudios.app:

http://pastebin.com/4dMxD8nb

Any Ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your code is not able to find facebook API classes at **runtime**. Ensure that you have `facebook.jar` in your classpath when you run your code.

If you have facebook SDK in your classpath while running the code and still facing the issue then try this:

> Just replace the android-support-v4.jar of your project that is in>lib
>   folder with android-support-v4.jar present in FacebookSDK>libs folder

as mentioned on these posts:

[{Facebook Login} java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413711/facebook-login-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-content-loca)

[Android facebook SDK doing error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError‎](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563593/android-facebook-sdk-doing-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
I have tried this but it still gives me an error at the exact same spot.