# Android facebook crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, cocos2d-x

I setup the Facebook sdk in Eclipse and I am using Facebook sdk 4.18.

I already added Facebook.jar to build path, but also crashes.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this); //Crash this line
    }

public void initFB(){
        Log.e("Facebook", "init facebook");
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

        Log.e("Facebook", "init facebook2");
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                Log.d("FB", "access token got.");

                fbLoginCallBack(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());

//              accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.d("FB", "CANCEL");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.d("FB", exception.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Error Message

> 12-22 16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.R$style 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   com.facebook.FacebookSdk.(FacebookSdk.java:83) 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   com.sidequest.taxi.taxi.onCreate(taxi.java:187) 12-22 16:57:29.620:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   12-22 16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
>   12-22 16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>   12-22 16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
>   12-22 16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) 12-22 16:57:29.620:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151) 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 12-22 16:57:29.620:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   12-22 16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684) 12-22
>   16:57:29.620: E/AndroidRuntime(19402): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You might have added it to the IDE path, but not to the path of your app. What does your `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. So no build.gradle

Comment: Try to put FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

Comment: why you think you can't use gradle with Eclipse? Why you use Eclipse at all?

Comment: Thanks your reply. But not work

Comment: I am using cocos2dx in Eclipse. But I don't know how to setup cocos2dx in Android Studio.

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3563593/1684864

Answer (score 1):

@Manlok Wong I am also facing this problem, So the solution is like

FacebookSdk. sdkInitialize (this); 
It is not properly taking the class

So, try this 
`FacebookSdk. sdkInitialize (Your Activity. this);`

And in **Application** class, in **onCreate () ** Method

`FacebookSdk. sdkInitialize (getApplicationContext ());`

Comment: Thanks for reply. FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(YourActivity.this); or FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); I already tried. But not work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

//or

FacebookAPI.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: the method he is calling is static, no need for constructor initialisation

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export Tab.

Make sure that "Facebook.jar" is checked for Export.

Comment: Make sure that the "gen" folder is before the "src" folder in Order and Export Tab. Also try "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties" and then cleaning the project.

Comment: Also, its better to import facebook sdk as a library rather than the jar file.

Comment: FacebookSDK 4.18 is using in Android Studio. So I download the Facebook.aar is not jar. I convert aar to jar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, our Android app was completly crashing (in Android 8 only) whenever a call to `logInWithReadPermissions()` was made:

```
/* This caused an immediate crash of the application - wrapping with 
   try/catch failed to "catch" any unhandled expection that may have been
   causing the crash */
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS);
```

It turns out that the inclusion of the `android:screenOrientation` attribute in our manifest's `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` activity was the cause of the crash:

```xml
<!-- Causes crash -->
<activity 
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Updating the `<acitivty/>` as follows fixed the bug:

```xml
<!-- Resolved the crash -->
<activity 
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

As part of my investigation into the cause of this bug, I also updated the project's FacebookSDK dependancy from `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0` to the more recent `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.0`.

Hope this helps someone!